# navMeshAgent.SetPath(path); Not working if distance too far

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a weird issue using navMeshAgent.SetPath(path);
Most of the time navMeshAgent.SetPath() works how I intend it too, but sometimes if the path is a long path or a u shape, lets say a wall is inbetween the enemy and the player, then SetPath will be broken causing the enemy to just stand in place not knowing where to path to. Which is weird because

if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete)

is showing as true.. Not sure what I can do to fix this? Using SetDestination works a lot better, but so many issues with performance. Anyone else encounter this SetPath issue? Any fix?

SetPath not working if distance is too far

Comment: SetPath ? where are you getting the path from in the first place? it is normal to use set destination that uses the mechanics to work the path out..   what are you doing that causes performance issues?